# Overcoming sharing settings

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-sharing

I have a Owd for account object is Public read only.I want to give Public read/write access for particular profile using Apex code.Is it possible withsharing Keyword?If it possible please give some hints of code

Answer (score 1):

Always pursue a declarative solution first. In regards to sharing, are you able to achieve that with Sharing Rules? Sharing Rules provide the ability to grant users with "read/write" access to your accounts based on ownership (allow other users access to a record based on who's its owner), or criteria based (share accounts with users based on certain values in certain fields).
The "with sharing" keyword will only ensure the declarative settings in are effect while a piece of code is running.